# Merging two Dataframes based on subject id

Tags: python, pandas, merge, jupyter-notebook

I have two dataframes defined as:

```
dataframe1 = pd.DataFrame( [[123, "ABC", "DEF", "GHI"],
                            [123, "ABC", "DEF", "GHI"],
                            [123, "ABC", "DEF", "GHI"],
                            [456, "JKL", "MNO", "PQR"],
                            [456, "JKL", "MNO", "PQR"],
                            [456, "JKL", "MNO", "PQR"]],
    columns=["ID",
            "Attr1", "Attr2", "Attr3"],
    )

dataframe2 = pd.DataFrame( [["1", "A", 123],
                            ["2", "A", 123],
                            ["1", "C", 456],
                            ["1", "B", 456],
                            ["2", "B", 123],
                            ["2", "C", 456]],
    columns=["ROW","LOCATION","ID"],
    )
```

I want to merge these two dataframe based on ID number. I have tried merge function as

```
pd.merge(dataframe1,dataframe2, on = 'ID')
```

However, that does not generate my desired result. I want an output with the same dimension of the original data.

```
    ID ROW LOCATION Attr1 Attr2 Attr3
0  123   1        A   ABC   DEF   GHI
1  123   2        A   ABC   DEF   GHI
2  123   2        B   ABC   DEF   GHI
3  456   1        B   JKL   MNO   PQR
4  456   1        C   JKL   MNO   PQR
5  456   2        C   JKL   MNO   PQR
```

Comment: How are you getting the above results? how do you distinguish from 123 being matched to the 3 rows that contain 123? Explain how you get your results

Comment: Voting to close since we'd have to guess at the desired join methodology in order to answer this.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are trying to get?

```
df_merge = pd.merge(dataframe1, dataframe2, on = ['ID']).drop_duplicates(ignore_index = True)
df_merge[['ID', 'ROW', 'LOCATION', 'Attr1', 'Attr2', 'Attr3']]
```

Comment: You code gives results for this small dataset. However, when I tried for a large dataset it increases the number of rows. I want to fixed the number of rows in the output dataframe same as the original two dataframes. Since, two dataframe having the same length. I want the same length of the output dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

To get your desired result, you can sort each dataframe (both on `ID` and `dataframe2` on `LOCATION` and `ROW` as well) and then use `concat` to join them horizontally on their indexes, dropping the `ID` column from `dataframe1`:

```py
df1 = dataframe1.sort_values(['ID']).reset_index(drop=True)
df2 = dataframe2.sort_values(['ID', 'LOCATION', 'ROW']).reset_index(drop=True)
pd.concat([df2,df1.drop('ID', axis=1)], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  ROW LOCATION   ID Attr1 Attr2 Attr3
0   1        A  123   ABC   DEF   GHI
1   2        A  123   ABC   DEF   GHI
2   2        B  123   ABC   DEF   GHI
3   1        B  456   JKL   MNO   PQR
4   1        C  456   JKL   MNO   PQR
5   2        C  456   JKL   MNO   PQR
```

Comment: I tried your way. However, it does not work properly because of sorting. There is no guarantee of matching the rows of two dataframes. I want to match the rows also.

Comment: @python_stat unfortunately it's not clear from your question how you want to join the two dataframes, and I just interpreted it as best I could. If you could edit your question with some more detail I'm sure this could be adapted to suit.

Answer (score 1):

Although the exact logic is unclear, it looks like you want a merge in order of the duplicates.

For this you can add a secondary key:

```
(dataframe1
 .assign(ID2=lambda d: d.groupby('ID').cumcount())
 .merge(dataframe2.assign(ID2=lambda d: d.groupby('ID').cumcount()),
       on=['ID', 'ID2'])
)
```

Output:

```
    ID Attr1 Attr2 Attr3  ID2 ROW LOCATION
0  123   ABC   DEF   GHI    0   1        A
1  123   ABC   DEF   GHI    1   2        A
2  123   ABC   DEF   GHI    2   2        B
3  456   JKL   MNO   PQR    0   1        C
4  456   JKL   MNO   PQR    1   1        B
5  456   JKL   MNO   PQR    2   2        C
```